# Locking multiple rows in MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

To lock two rows in MySQL should I be using:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id=? OR id=? FOR UPDATE;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id=? AND id=? FOR UPDATE;
```

I obviously am inside a transaction just not sure whether it should be `AND` or `OR`?

Answer (score 7):

If your `WHERE` clause is `id=1 AND id=2` then no rows will be eligible for inclusion in the result set and  so no rows will be locked.

To lock both rows you need to use `id=1 OR id=2`, that way both rows will be included in the result set and will be locked.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it matters. According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html), locks will be acquired only for rows that "qualify for inclusion in the result set."

> For **SELECT ... FOR UPDATE**, locks are acquired for scanned rows, and expected to be released for rows that do not qualify for inclusion in the result set (for example, if they do not meet the criteria given in the WHERE clause).

**Update**

You may be able to use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to check what rows are locked for each type of `SELECT`.

You can read more about reading the lock [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/how-can-i-find-who-holds-the-lock-based-on-the-hex-dumped) and [here](http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-lock-monitor).

Comment: It does matter whether it's AND or OR, IMO. See @jleahy's answer.